# Unable to get image data in an API along with json data for registration

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to create a register API in which I have username,email, password input along with an image field.I am unable to receive and process the data properly.The default user class is extended to store image field.
I have this extended user **model**:-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return os.path.join("user_%s" % instance.user.username,"user_{0}.{1}" .format(instance.user.username,fileExtension))

# Create your models here.
class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
    has_voted=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    voted_item=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='none')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

These are the **serializers**:-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Userprofile

class UserprofileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Userprofile
        fields=['display_picture']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','email','password1','password2']
```

this is the **path/url**:-

```
path('register',views.FileUploadView.as_view(),name='Register'),
```

this is the **view**:-

```
@csrf_exempt
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes=[MultiPartParser,FormParser]

    def register(self,request):
        display_picture=request.FILES["display_picture"]
        data=json.loads(request.data["data"])
        #saving data using serializers
        return JsonResponse({'message': "Registered Successfully!"},status=200)
```

I am getting this issue which says:-

path('register',views.FileUploadView.as_view(),name='Register'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are decorating a class like a function,thats why your code is breaking.

In order to use a decorator on a class, you can do either of the two approaches:

1) Decorating the class:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt,name='dispatch')
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes=[MultiPartParser,FormParser]
    def register(self,request):             

        display_picture=request.FILES["display_picture"] 
        data=json.loads(request.data["data"])         

        #saving data using serializers 
        return JsonResponse({'message': "Registered Successfully!"},status=200)
```

2) Decorating in URL only:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

path('register',csrf_exempt(view.FileUploadView.as_view()))
```

You can read in detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views).